# Is it Possible to have ASP.NET role based form authentication and authorization without web.sitemap?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, authorization, user-roles

I have made an ASP.NET 4.5.2 web form application. Recently I implemented role based form authentication and authorization by following [this](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Role-based-Authorization-and-Authentication-in-ASPNet.aspx) article.

In this article, the writer used a `web.sitemap` file. Here is the web.sitemap file I made by following the article:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode url="~/Home.aspx" title="Home"  description="Home Page">
    <siteMapNode url="" title="Patients and Physician"  description="Patient and Physician Details">
      <siteMapNode url="~/EnrollPatient.aspx" title="Enroll Patient"  description="EnrollPatient page" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/EnterPatientDiagnosis.aspx" title="Enter Patient Diagnosis"  description="Enter Patient Diagnosis Page" />
      <siteMapNode url="ViewPatientInformation.aspx" title="View Patient Information"  description="View Patient Information Page" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/SearchPhysician.aspx" title="Search Physician"  description="Search Physician Page" />
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode url="~/javascript:;" title="Admin"  description="AdminPanel">
      <siteMapNode url="~/Admin/AddPhysician.aspx" title="Add Physician"  description="Add Physician Page" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/Admin/AdminPanel.aspx" title="Admin Panel"  description="User Moditification" />
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode url="~/" title="Login/Register"  description="Login Or Register">
      <siteMapNode url="~/Login.aspx" title="Login"  description="Login" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/Register.aspx" title="Register"  description="Register" />
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

And this is a part of my web.config file:

```
  <system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms defaultUrl="~/Home.aspx" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880"></forms>
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
  <siteMap enabled ="true" defaultProvider="SiteMap">
    <providers>
      <add name="SiteMap" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/Web.sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
    </providers>
  </siteMap>
  <system.web>
```

From what I have found on the internet that it is used to populate `<asp:Menu>` control items. Although, I'm not using any `<asp:Menu>` control.

My first question is, does `web.sitemap` has any influence on the authorization? With some changes in the`<provider>` section, can I not use the `web.sitemap` file?

My Second question is, what is `~/javascript:;` doing in the third parent `SiteMapNode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the sitemap does not have an effect on the authorization. In a sitemap, you can add security-trimming to your menu by adding the roles.

You can restrict access to your website (or parts of it) by including the `<authorization>` element in a web.config file. A good overview provides this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/role-based-authorization-cs#step-1-defining-role-based-url-authorization-rules). The following snippet grants only administrators access to the folder:

```
  <authorization>    
       <allow roles="Administrators" />    
       <deny users="*"/>    
  </authorization>
```

So in order to protect your website, use the `<authorization>` element. If you do not need the sitemap, you can remove it by deleting this section from your web.config:

```
  <siteMap enabled ="true" defaultProvider="SiteMap">
    <providers>
      <add name="SiteMap" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/Web.sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
    </providers>
  </siteMap>
```

In addition, you can also remove your sitemap files. For details on Sitemaps in ASP.NET, see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy2ykkab(v=vs.100).aspx).